# Deployment Error in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have started getting the following error after I have updated my java. I could not able to find a way to fix it. I even uninstalled and reinstalled Xamarin Android Player.

[image]

[image]

By the way, I have deleted `jdk1.6.9` already but it still pointing the same directory.

[image]

But I checked the Xamarin options (Tools-->Options-->Xamarin --> Android), it points to `jdk1.7`
[image]

Comment: Did you restart visual Studio after pointing to the new location?

Comment: Are you trying to deploy to emulator or device?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin doesn't work properly when you have installed two version of java .
Uninstall one version and try just with on of them .

Answer (score 0):

There's a conflict in the version of java that the visual studio xamarin is fetching.

Answer (score 0):

After Adding the path in **Tools-->Options-->Xamarin --> Android**
Also check path set in your environment variables in My Computer properties,

> Set the same path till bin folder as for JAVA_HOME

it also causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for bring up this question.

You must ***uninstall*** a version of **java** that not compatible with your **android** **SDK**.its better that install java and android SDK and NDK and also xamarin for visual studio manually(do not install with ***visual studio*** install file).i promis you that this problem and a lot of problem like it is solved when we ***setup*** dependency of  xamarin manually .finaly i said this that i can catch all output of xamarin project in all platforms,**simulators** and **real** **devices**.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall jdk which is pointed to that path from Tools -> Options -> Xamarin and then re install it and update environment variables and then set its jdk path in xamarin.